# PHP email from form pluralise a tag

Tags: php, forms, email

I am new to PHP but I am using it to take information from a form to send a bespoke email to the people that fill it in. I want to pluralise one of the answers but not sure how:

```
$a6 = $_POST['6'];
```

Hello $a6 (this works as it takes the information from $a6)

*Hello Bob*

A group of $a6s (this doesnt work as it is trying to find $a6s)

*A group of Bobs (this is what I want to achieve)*

Thanks in advance

Comment: echo `$a6 . 's';`

Comment: `echo "A group of {$a6}s"`

Comment: @RiggsFolly Your second example will fail as there is no `$a6s` variable. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.simple

Comment: Note that the technique of appending "s" may not always generate a correct pluralization. If you search https://packagist.org for "plural" or "inflector" there are a number of libraries that can do this more reliably.